# Is there a way to identify the column where a row actually has data in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have worked with pandas before, but not extensively. I have created this pretty vast dataset. I want to convert my csv files to a panda, which I know how to do by doing something like:

```
data = pd.read_csv(fileName, engine='python', delimiter=',')
```

The only thing is that some of the data is sparse. For example the data is something like:

```
name     total     sub_1     time     sub_2     time     diff    
kate      11        75      1/1/19     74     1/2/19      1
kelly      1         6      1/1/19     NaN     NaN        NaN
david     10        54      1/1/19     74     1/2/19      20
```

only the data could go up to sub_300 in some cases. So having this kind of data for about 700 people and very sparse is not super helpful in this form.

I would like to add a few columns to the end of the data frame that will give some more useful information. I would like to something like `Last Submit Time` and `Last Submission`.

I would like `Last Submit Time` to be the last time there was a value for and ``Last Submission``` to be the last value for sub_x.

Is there any way to do this in pandas? I am not sure there is any way I can do it since the sub_x column varies. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In this case the values in your new column would be `74, 6, 74` right for `Last Submission` right?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: The question title doesn't appear to be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the columns are in chronological order, you can define a function to process the last non-NaN entry for each row. Something like this

```
def last_non_nan(row, colname):
    """
    colname is used to slice a row and keep only relevant entries
    """
    sliced = row[row.index.str.contains(colname)]
    # last_col is the column name of the last non NaN entry
    last_col = sliced[sliced.isnull()==False].index[-1]
    return sliced[last_col]
```

And then you can add columns as you need:

```
df['last_submission'] = df.apply(last_non_nan, colname='sub', axis=1)
df['last_submit_time'] = df.apply(last_non_nan, colname='time', axis=1)
```

Comment: I was able to do this with a few edits and got things working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to find the last column with valid data:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.last_valid_index(), axis=1)
```

Returns:

```
0      diff
1    time_1
2      diff
dtype: object
```

However, I think you will be much better off by unpivotting the dataframe for later analysis. Check [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: I will try this. I believe this will work as expected! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a number of options that give you a fair bit of flexibility when processing NaNs in csv files.  Once you have read in the the csv file, you could test for NaN while writing your function to calculate those additional fields you mention.